# Save a variable number of CSS styles as a JS variable for show/hide?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let me preface by saying I don't have a ton of Javascript experience. I have a CSS class specifically used to show/hide things with a button click on my site. The progress bars are shown by default, and have their various colors and styles shown no problem. Using the following code, the button will hide the progress bars correctly.

```
    function showhide() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("showhideclass");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i ++) {
      if (x[i].style.display === "none") {
        x[i].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
```

However, when the button is clicked again to show the progress bars again, the color and other styling does not show up. I know this is because of the line `x[i].style.display = "block";` but I do not know how to save the CSS styling as a variable in this function to have it reapplied on "Show" click. I've tried the following code, and it will still hide the progress bars properly, but it does not display them again on second click.

```
function showhide() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("showhideclass");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i ++) {
      var elstyle = window.getComputedStyle(x[i]);
      if (x[i].style.display === "none") {
        x[i].style.display = elstyle;
      } else {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here, does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: First of all you are setting the display property to the computed style object, you might want to use "elstyle.display" instead (`x[i].style.display = elstyle;`). This property will be "none" for sure since you are checking for this in the if clause. Maybe just use "block" like in the upper snippet.

Comment: This was it! I changed `x[i].style.display = elstyle;` to `x[i].style = elstyle;` and it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use something like this.

Define some css class with a `display: none` property and toggle the class on the elements itself via button-press.
All properties such as `display: flex`, `display: block`, or `display: none` will not be overwritten.

```js
function showhide() {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("showhideclass");
  [...elements].forEach(e => e.classList.toggle("hidden"));
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="showhideclass">1</p>
<p class="showhideclass">2</p>
<p class="showhideclass">3</p>
<p class="showhideclass">4</p>
<button onclick="showhide()">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: I tried this function instead of what I currently have and added the CSS class to my styles, but for some reason the button's not hiding the progress bars at all. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here!

Answer (score 0):

@jns had the right of it. The following code works perfectly as intended, with the styles being saved for each progress bar as it is hidden and shown.

```
  function showhide() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("showhideclass");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i ++) {
      var elstyle = window.getComputedStyle(x[i]);
      if (x[i].style.display === "none") {
        x[i].style = elstyle;
        //x[i].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
```

Edit: the bot yelled at me, so I will further explain. Changing the line `x[i].style.display = elstyle;` resolved the issue; removing `.display` causes this line to apply the saved style AS a style, instead of as the display property.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).